# Apply conditional OR to a variable

Tags: java, initialization, logical-operators

Having a variable initialized with zero I want to change itsvalue if there is a value different from zero compared to it. This thing works in Javascipt but it seems it doesn't in Java.

```
int val = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < anArrayOfObjects.length; i++) {
    val = val || anArrayOfObjects[i].length;
}
return val;
```

The error says:

> Operator '||' cannot be applied to 'int', 'int'

How should it be changed to work?

Comment: Why are you setting the `val` variable in the `for` loop? Don't you want to increment it instead?

Comment: Moreover it is not a *logical OR* that you want but instead a *conditional OR*!

Comment: @LudovicFeltz I don't want to increment it, just to store a value different from zero if there is one in the array

Comment: Do you want the last non zero size of your array? Can't you can break the loop at the first no zero value instead?

Comment: @LudovicFeltz any positive value should be fine, so yes, it could stop after that one is accomplished

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [JLS - 15.24. Conditional-Or Operator `||`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.24)
:

> Each operand of the conditional-or operator must be of type **boolean** or **Boolean**, or a compile-time error occurs.

You need to handle this in a different way, perhaps something like:

```
val = val != 0 ? val : anArrayOfObjects[i].length;
```

The logical `||` operator in JavaScript can be used with any primitive value or object. Its result will be based in whether the value is **truthy** or **falsy**.

Answer (score 3):

To give some context (other answers cover the 'java way' to do this already), the notion that a 0 value is 'false' is generally refered to as 'in this language, **0 is falsy**. In most languages, things are **truthy** (if used in a place where only a boolean is acceptable, it is treated the same as `true`), unless they are on an explicit list of **falsy** things.

The problem is, languages disagree on the list. This causes endless confusion. `null` and `undefined` (if a language has the notion) are universally falsy. But it gets more complicated after that. Is the empty string falsy? Is an empty list? What about a custom data type that has an iterator option and if you were to call it, it would return no elements? For example, a jQuery selector object that refers to 0 DOM elements, is that *truthy* or *falsy*?

What about the string `"0"`? That acts as the int 0 in many places, so should it be falsy?

Even weirder, in linux shells (such as `/bin/bash`), the situation with numbers is reversed; 0 is truthy and all other values are falsy. This seems ridiculous, but it actually makes sense within the confines of what bash and such are meant for: processes can return a single byte as 'error value', and 0 is the universal indicator of 'no error; all is normal', hence why bash works with inverse truthy/falsy on numbers. truthy matches 'no errors' and falsy matches 'some errors', which is a sensible way to do it.

Which gets us to java: Java decided that the few characters saved by having truthy/falsy in the language is absolutely, in no way, worth the complexity and confusion that adding it would entail. Thus, java is absolutist. `true` is truthy. `false` is falsy. All other values if used in a boolean context are a compiler error.

That is to say: No, java does not let you use `someIntExpr || defaultValue` as a quick way to rewrite a 0 value, and crucially, never* will. Try `someIntExpr == 0 ? defaultValue : someIntExpr` for that, or integrate it straight into your API call, so instead of writing: `someHashMap.get("someKey") || "default"`, which isn't java and would not compile, try: `someHashMap.getOrDefault("someKey", "default")`. That's not the only java API that has built-in support for passing default values along.

*) Opinions can change of course, but let's put it this way: *exceedingly* unlikely that enough of the community and the core committers would change their mind on this and allow a language change to introduce more truthy and falsy things.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `val = val || anArrayOfObjects[i];`, perhaps try
`val = (anArrayOfObjects[i] > 0 ? anArrayOfObjects[i] : val)`

This updates val with the new value only if it is larger than 0.

Comment: the question implies that anArrayOfObjects is an array of arrays, or at least an array of objects of some type that has a public field named `length` – it is not itself an integer. Also, the question implies the job is to find the FIRST non-zero length, which your code doesn't do even if you fixed the `length` oversight.

Comment: @rzwitserloot Guess I missed those implications... but yeah, I see where you're coming from. Fortunately a lot of other people already wrote (including yourself, looks good!) more applicable answers.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a ternary operator.

```
val = val == 0 ? anArrayOfObjects[i].length : val;
```

Basically, what you need to do is to find the first non-zero `anArrayOfObjects[i].length` or return `0` if none. A Stream API approach might be a more intuitive option.

```
Stream.of(anArrayOfObjects)
        .mapToInt(i -> i.length)
        .filter(i -> i != 0)
        .findFirst()
        .orElse(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int val = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < anArrayOfObjects.length && val == 0; i++) {
    val = anArrayOfObjects[i].length;
}
return val;
```

Or

```
return Stream.of(anArrayOfObjects)    // Stream<T[]>
    .mapToInt(o -> o.length)          // IntStream
    .filter(len -> len != 0)
    .findFirst()                      // OptionalInt
    .orElse(0);                       // int
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
int val = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < anArrayOfObjects.length; i++) {
  if(val!=0){
  val = anArrayOfObjects[i].length;
  }  
}
return val;
```